# Trying to set the height of a cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, after heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Since `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I was assuming that if I wanted to modify the height from within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I could do so. It seems I can't. I've tested via `NSLog` and if I change `cell.frame.size.height`, the change is stored in there properly, but the cell itself doesn't take on the new size (it's using the one I set in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`).

Is there another method that would adjust the cell's height that's called at some point after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? If not, is there another way around this? I need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` since I'm deciding on the fly whether to randomly add an image to each cell in turn.

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is a delegate call.  Is your delegate set on the table?

Comment: Yes, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are both being called properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the code that randomly decides to add an image in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method instead.

Use a `NSMutableDictionary` to keep track of the `NSIndexPath`'s that use images.

Comment: This isn't really an option, since I'm using Core Data and an NSFetchedResultsController to filter the results after they've been generated. Doing this will change the indexPaths, so things would get horribly out of whack, wouldn't it?

Comment: In that case, if your Core Data object has some sort of unique ID (or event the objectID), you could use that as the NSDictionary's key instead of the indexPath.

Comment: It does, yes, but how would that work? When using heightForRowAtIndexPath, I'd add the ID of the object to an array if it's decided it'll be an image.. then when doing cellAtRowForIndexPath, I'd lay the image out if its ID is found in that array?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it.

Comment: Would you recommend anything else, before I go tapping that in like a crazed fool? :)

Comment: I've used NSDictionary a lot for this kind of thing, so yes. If you use the NSDictionary method instead, you could even cache the row heights, which has some performance benefits in larger lists of items: myDictionary[myObjectID] = @(rowHeight)

Answer (score 6):

`UITableViewDelegate heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `UITableView rowHeight` are the only mechanisms for specifying the height of a cell.  The tableview itself is resizing your cell based on these; you cannot yourself set your cell frame and expect it to work.

The best thing you can do is to be able to calculate, in advance, your cell height before the cell is created.  I'll often define a `+ (CGFloat) cellHeightWithDatum: (id) datum forWidth: (CGFloat) tableWidth` method to call on my cell class from `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.  Datum here is the model that drives the cell's content.  This method then looks at the model and figures out how tall the cell needs to be.

If you absolutely need to change the cell's height once the cell is created you can do this by asking the tableview to reload the cell, or to refresh the entire table w/out calling reloadData.  This trick is done by:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

To reload a single cell:  `UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Answer (score 0):

You should just randomly decide sometime before cellForRowAtIndexPath and then store a flag in a data structure in your dataSource for each indexPath whether there is going to be an image there or not. You could just do it in heightForRowAtIndexPath if the work to decide whether there will be an image is inexpensive. Something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL showingAnImage = arc4random() % 2;
    // self.imageIndexPaths is some data structure that lets you associate a value to an index path
    self.imageIndexPaths[indexPath] = @(showingAnImage);
    if (showingAnImage){
        // return height of a cell with an image
    } else {
        // return height of a cell without an image
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.imageIndexPaths[indexPath] boolValue]){
        // Configure for image
    } else {
        // Configre without image
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Changing the cell's size in cellForRowAtIndexPath: will not work.

Comment: I'm using Core Data and an NSFetchedResultsController to filter the results after they've been generated. Doing this will change the indexPaths, so things would get horribly out of whack, wouldn't it?

Comment: Looks like Vinny Coyne beat me to it!

Comment: Why do you say it would get out of whack? This way you will be predetermining whether the cell at an index path has an image or not, regardless of how the data you're showing in the table view is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of the index that needs to expand.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self shouldBeExpanded:indexPath.row]) { //method that checks if this cell should be expanded. You'll need to check the array if it contains the row.
        return kCellHeightExpanded;
    }

    return kCellNormalHeight;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     //set cell to be expanded
     [self expandCellAt:indexPath.row]; //method that sets which cell is expanded. You'll need to implement this yourself. Use an array to track which row should be expanded

     //this causes heightForRowAtIndexPath: to be called again
     [tableView beginUpdates];
     [tableView endUpdates];
}
```